# convert int to str in django template tags

Tags: django

I have to use an int value as str in a template. Here is the code

```
<a href="{% url staticPageEdit id=item.id%}">{{ item.id}}</a>
```

But when I run render the template I got TemplateSyntaxError
Description of the error is:Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'staticPageEdit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 1L}' not found.
My problem here is that item.id is a number value. but my staticPageEdit page is expecting a string. here is de urls.py lines for this url

```
url(r'^staticPage/Edit/$',views.staticPageEdit,{'id':'-1'},name='staticPageEdit'),
url(r'^staticPage/Edit/(?P<id>/d+)/$',views.staticPageEdit,name='staticPageEdit'),
```

I want to some how send a string value instead of a number. is that possible?

Comment: Shouldn't regex be `(?P<id>\d+)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this regex:

```
r'^staticPage/Edit/(?P<id>/d+)/$'
```

should be

```
r'^staticPage/Edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use stringformat filter.
The code would be something like this

```
<a href="{% url staticPageEdit id=item.id|stringformat:"i"%}">{{ item.id}}</a>
```